# How to abbreviate journal name in citation

Tags: citing, acronyms

I'm writing my research proposal and my supervisor wants me to abbreviate the journal name (and remove part of the month from the publication date). How can I achieve that?

*Edit:*
I am using BibTeX and my .bib file holds the full journal name. I writing using Emacs on an Arch Linux machine. I don't really mind switching to other LaTeX format but I don't know anything about them.

Comment: This is very little information. How do you create your references? Do you use bibtex and a bitex style or are you using biblatex. Long story short, please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: If you have to quickly finish the proposal, I recommend to duplicate and open the `.bib` file and use the `search and replace` function of your preferred editor to simply replace the journal names with appropriate abbreviations. You can also delete the month entries. Ugly, but quick...

Comment: @Andy: As you said, ugly but quick. I was hoping for something more general for future work. Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111724/is-there-a-transparent-way-to-automatically-abbreviate-journal-names

Comment: for mathematical citation, I use the amsscinet database, which include the journal and fjournal filed, the journal field is the abbrevation.

Answer (score 33):

A while back I created a package and some BibTeX styles for automatic journal abbreviations that uses the ISSN database to do exactly this:
https://github.com/compholio/jabbrv

This is now included as an Overleaf template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/automatic-journal-abbreviations/mxfsdscmvxcr

Edit: Changed link to git repository (old link: http://www.compholio.com/latex/jabbrv/)

Comment: @Comppholio Is this on CTAN? I've wondered in the past about providing something that at least in the first instance looks similar (_i.e._ a 'magic' macro that converts full names to abbreviations), so I'll be taking a  look at how you've tackled this.

Comment: @Joseph No, I've not yet contributed anything to CTAN.  I recently got tired of making new BibTeX styles all the time and decided to use some of the techniques from developing jabbrv to make a package that processes BibTeX files using a simpler style file syntax.

Comment: Very good package!!! It also abbreviates initials. It is very easy to use. Just copy sty, bst, and ldf files to your working directory.

Comment: Dear @Comppholio, is it also possible to remove the long line which is automatically put for repeated authors in consecutive references?

Comment: that looks very interesting! Is it also compatible with `biblatex` and `biber`, or does it require `bibtex`?

Comment: I wish it had styles for Physical Review/RevTeX

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist It's not that difficult to modify the styles, and I do have one: https://github.com/compholio/jabbrv/blob/master/jabbrv_apsrev4-1.bst

Comment: I have incorporated Compholio's package into an example Overleaf document, so that anyone who uses Overleaf can also use this package: https://www.overleaf.com/read/drzdrzrgrrrp

Comment: Overleaf now provides this as a template here: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/automatic-journal-abbreviations/mxfsdscmvxcr

Comment: In jabbrv.sty, you implement "Redefinitions for diacritical marks" because you say they are "ignored by ISO-4". This has the (pleasing) consequence that the abbreviation rule for "bìolog-" (with a 'grave-i') applies also to the English "biology" (with a 'plan-i'). But why do you think the diacritical marks are ignored by ISO 4? That document in fact says, "Diacritic marks shall be retained in the word abbreviations. For languages where an alternative spelling without diacritics is also possible, this alternative may be used instead." It gives examples such as "médecine = méd."

Comment: What you are supposed to do, which is not technically supported yet, is to keep the diacritical marks when shortening the abbreviation.  So, the pattern for "bìolog-" applies to "biology" officially and you are supposed to ignore the diacritical marks for the purposes of comparison.

Comment: @Compholio But where in the ISO 4 standard or LTWA/ISSN manuals/web pages is it stated that you are supposed to ignore the diacritical marks for the purposes of comparison? And if it is not stated explicitly (at least I haven't been able to find it), how did you deduce that rule?

Comment: @linguisticturn Section 4.9: "Abbreviated titles are considered identical when they are composed of the same letters or characters irrespective of diacritics or other punctuation."

Comment: @Compholio I see. Well, *strictly speaking,* that section only says that the diacritics should be ignored when comparing the **abbreviations** of the **full titles**; it says nothing about whether the diacritics should be ignored also when comparing the original **unabbreviated individual words.** Further, *strictly speaking,* the thrust of that section is about disambiguating the (identical-but-for-the-diacritics) abbreviated full titles, not about how the abbreviations are to be formed in the first place. Buuuuut… I suppose it is not unreasonable to extrapolate a bit in this case. Thank you!

Comment: @linguisticturn Yeah, that's how I originally interpreted it as well.  Some time ago (I want to say 2016) the LWTA changed how they reported a _lot_ of the abbreviations and that clause appears to be the source of the change.  Since that change, if you look up "biolog" in the LWTA you'll see that the it finds "bìolog-" as the appropriate entry and the match code "mul" (multiple).

Comment: @Compholio What finally persuaded me is the abbreviation for *expérience,* with the 'acute-e'. On the one hand, ISO 4 itself says in Sec. 4.9 that ***Expérience** et innovations en éducation* should be abbreviated as ***Exp.** innov. éduc.*. On the other hand, the only relevant LTWA entry is the 'plain-e' "Experien-    exp.   eng, fre"; there is no separate entry for any related 'acute-e' word or stem, such as "Expérien-". Furthermore, there are simply no French words with the stem "experien-"; there is only [*expérience*](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9E3429).

Comment: @Compholio So, if it were true that the 'plain-e' and 'acute-e' must be treated as distinct as far as the original unabbreviated words, then 1. the LTWE entry "Experien-    exp.    eng, fre" would have applied to no French words at all, and 2. the LTWE wouldn't have been able to reproduce one of the few abbreviations that are explicitly endorsed by the original ISO 4. Thus, the 'plain-e' and 'acute-e' must **not** be treated as distinct as far as the original unabbreviated words.

Comment: @Compholio (Although argument 2. is weakened by the fact that ISO 4 says that the Spanish *Experiencias* is abbreviated as *Exp.*, and this is apparently not covered by the LTWA, since the language annotations for "Experien-" don't include 'spa'. So there is at least one abbreviation explicitly endorsed by the original ISO 4 that the current LTWA can't reproduce.)

Answer (score 24):

EDIT: There is an elegant way now with `biber` 0.9.6. Together with `biblatex` 1.7. the data can be changed on the fly without changing the input `.bib` file itself. It utilizes the `map` feature of `biber` as described in section 3.1.1 of the manual. The `biber.conf` file looks like this:

```xml
<map>
  <bibtex>
  BMAP_OVERWRITE 1
    <globalfield journal>
      BMAP_MATCH Physical\sReview
      BMAP_REPLACE "Phys. Rev."
    </globalfield>
  </bibtex>
</map>
```

which would replace `Physical Review` with `Phys. Rev.` Please find a verbose explanation [in my answer to this question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34295/biblatex-how-to-insert-dots-into-abbreviated-journal-names-in-bibliography/35818#35818)

/EDIT

One possible way would be to come up with a work abbreviation. Then, you use the editor of your choice and `search and replace` the journal title with the work abbreviation. Let's say the journal is `A long journal name` and you call it `alj`. You replace `Journal={A long journal name}` with `Journal=alj` in the bibtex file. Now, you can make two `bibtex` files: `short.bib` and `long.bib` with the content `@string{alj="A l. J. N."}` and `@string{alj="A long journal name"}`, respectively. Whenever you feel like it, you can add another way to display the journal title.

MWE (you could have provided that):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Test\cite{brown08}

\bibliography{long,cvpubs}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\end{document}
```

use either `\bibliography{long,cvpubs}` or `\bibliography{short,cvpubs}` for long or short journal titles.

cvpubs.bib:

```
@article{brown08,
    Author = {Seth Brown and Michael Cole and Albert Erives},
    Journal = alj,
    Title = {Evolution of the holozoan ribosome biogenesis regulon},
    Volume = {9},
    Year = {2008},
    Pages = {113}
```

short.bib:

```
@string{alj="A l. J. N."}
```

long.bib

```
@string{alj="A long journal name"}
```

leading to

[image: short example]
and
[image: long example]

Comment: Please note the the biber config file format will change for biber 0.9.7 because the current one is not easy to extend and it a bit confusing for the mapping options. The new one is XML and much easier to understand for mapping options. The manual has been re-written for 0.9.7 with examples. You can get 0.9.7 beta from sourceforge now in the development folder.

Answer (score 16):

You should be aware that the abbreviation is not arbitrary, because there is the standard [ISO 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4) that defines a [List of Title Word Abbreviations (LTWA)](http://www.issn.org/services/online-services/access-to-the-ltwa/). As far as I know, every abbreviation is unique, so that abbreviating/un-abbreviating should work unambigously in both directions.

The CAS has a small [online tool CASSI](http://cassi.cas.org/) that can be used to search for journal names and/or their official LTWA abbreviation.

JabRef has a [journal name abbreviation feature](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/help/JournalAbbreviations.php) that also uses the LTWA. This feature can be configured under Options → Manage journal abbreviations.

Answer (score 13):

I have made a little Python script that processes a bibtex database, searching for the journal names and replacing them with their official abbreviation (taken from the Jabref source): https://gist.github.com/FilipDominec/9ff081952dbc4aae1df657a56c3db4ea

Comment: I wanted to do that for so long now. I'll have a look at it

Comment: It took some 20 minutes to write the script. But it is surprisingly nontrivial to find an usable list of journal names... The world's academic community is obviously missing some central source of such information.

Comment: It lacks so much....

Comment: @Yotam you could of course still implement the un-abbreviation feature...

Comment: This script just does a find replace based on all the text in the bibtex file and I found that it replaces things in abstracts etc. if the journal title isn't specific enough.

Comment: @Yotam We would all be better off if journals just stopped caring about abbreviations at all. It truly is an extremely outdated practice.

Comment: It seems the "journallist.txt" is not there anymore. E.g. my browser gives "404: Not Found" and the script fails to execute with an error that seems like the list is empty.

Answer (score 11):

[betterbib](https://github.com/nschloe/betterbib) (a small project of mine) now gives you a choice on the journal names; short ones are the default.
Simply install with

```
pip install betterbib
```

and run it over your bib file:

```
betterbib update your.bib > out.bib
```

Use `--long-journal-name`/`-l` to switch to long journal names.

EDIT: The package has been update and now the `>` is necessary to make this work.

Comment: installs nicely but gives an error: betterbib bib.bib out.bib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/betterbib", line 6, in <module>
    from betterbib.cli.full import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/betterbib/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .__about__ import __version__, __author__, __author_email__, __website__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/betterbib/__about__.py", line 8, in <module>
    __copyright__ = u"Copyright (c) 2013-2019, {} <{}>".format(__author__, __author_email__)

Comment: Don't use Python 2 anymore, you probably got an ancient version.

Comment: Might be the case that the syntax of the example is obsolete? To make it work I  run `betterbib abbreviate-journal-names your.bib > out.bib`. Thanks for the great proyect.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a simple Python script that takes a bibtex file, and creates a copy of that file with journal names replaced by their abbreviations. It can be found here: https://gitlab.com/GuusAvis/abbreviate_journals .

In my case I really wanted something with little overhead (doing one thing and one thing only) that I could easily understand. This led me to try and use the script posted by @dominecf. However, it replaced more fields in my bibtex file than I wanted, and is based on a list of abbreviations that has in the mean time been outdated. I ended up editing [this script](https://gist.github.com/arahatashun/2d27d5e2694c3f1f25aa5cd624defe5f) posted on github in response to the one made by @dominecf, and combining it with the abbrv.jabref.org database such that it automatically remains up to date (the other script tries to pull a version that no longer exists).

It also allows choosing which abbreviation lists from the abbrv.jabref.org database to use. This can be useful, as there appear to be conflicts between those lists, potentially resulting in undesired behavior. This is what happened to me when using jabref to add abbreviations.

Hopefully there is someone who still finds this useful, almost twelve years after the original question was posed!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem. My solution

```
pipx install bibiso4
bibiso4 your_refs.bib > iso4_your_refs.bib
```