# Is there a tool for generating journal names' abbreviations

Tags: bibtex, acronyms

Having a BibTeT file with full journal titles in it, I'm looking for a tool to construct a list of abbreviations following [ISSN standard](http://www.issn.org/2-22660-LTWA.php) (it specifies how to abbreviate individual words, which should make it straightforward to generate abbreviations for any title).  I'm ware of JabRef, but it requires a list of title-abbreviation pairs and I don't want to do one by hand if I don't have to.  (I should add that the lists available from JabRef website do not cover the titles I have).

Comment: There are various lists for many major journal families online. I've found [this](http://www.ieee.org/documents/tjmnames.pdf) for IEEE for example. You can copy to a spreadsheet and import it later to JabRef.

Comment: @percusse: yes, there are various lists, but a general tool would save me time looking them up and possibly processing them further.

Comment: related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33441/how-to-abbreviate-journal-name-in-citation

Comment: The question linked in the comment above, even though is a little bit younger than this one, has attracted more and better answers. Regarding the specific question of "a tool", an answer is offered there: Mendeley.

Comment: Another tool is provided in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391997/45342): `betterbib`, a Python command line tool to improve bib files.

Answer (score 6):

For `jabref` there is already a [pretty extensive list](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/journals/journal_abbreviations_general.txt) with 1740 entries and for [the sciences](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/journals/journal_abbreviations_lifescience.txt) with 9700 entries.

Comment: I use this list already, but it only partially covers the titles I have.

Comment: I can not use this txt file. I downloaded it by jabref, but how to use it?

Comment: I have made a little Python script that processes a bibtex database, searching for the journal names and replacing them with their official abbreviation (taken from the Jabref database): https://gist.github.com/FilipDominec/9ff081952dbc4aae1df657a56c3db4ea

Answer (score 2):

math reviews/mathscinet has a list, [abbreviation of names of serials](http://www.ams.org/msnhtml/serials.pdf), in the form of a pdf file.  there's also a [corresponding csv file](http://www.ams.org/msnhtml/annser.csv) suitable for use with excel.  not precisely what is requested, but perhaps useful nonetheless.  i don't know whether is follows the issn standard to the letter; mr established many of its abbreviation principles before issn existed.