# Beamer print citation in frames with entrykey

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I am using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490049/towards-a-concise-fullcite-command) to define a `DeclareCiteCommand` which prints a bibkey as a footnote of a frame. I would like to add the `keyentry` so that the number is displayed as well.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage[%
          autocite=footnote,
          maxnames=2,
          autolang=hyphen,
          hyperref=true,
          abbreviate=true,
          doi=false,
          backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
    %minimum bib file
    \usepackage{filecontents}
        \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
        @Article{Doe2019,
            author  = {Doe, Jhon and Doe2, Jhon2},
            title   = {Some journal article},
            journal = {Fancy Journal},
            year    = {2019},
            volume  = {56},
            number  = {3},
            pages   = {1-99},
        }
        \end{filecontents}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}         

    %cite command to get abbreviated citation in frame
    \DeclareCiteCommand{\citeframe}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\printtext[beamercolorauthor]{%
            \printnames[family]{labelname}%
            \setunit{\addcomma\space}}%
        \printtext[beamercolornote]{%
            \printfield{journaltitle}%
            \setunit{\addspace}%
            \printtext[parens]{%
                \printdate}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

    %tikz command to get footnote with source (could be defined in a general cite command if a newline could be define between each citations when multiple citation per frame)
    \newcommand{\rightsource}[1]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=0.3cm,above left] at (current page.south east) {\footnotesize %
            \begin{tabular}{r}#1\end{tabular}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Introduction}
        this relies on this article \cite{Doe2019}

        \rightsource{\citeframe{Doe2019}}   
    \end{frame} 
    \end{document}
```

output:
[image: MWE output]

desired output (here I added the number manually but I want it automatic):
[image: desired output]

I have tried adding `\thefield{entrykey}` after the `prenote`, as seen for articles, but I get `undefined control sequence error` in beamer... I am more used to TikZ or article class, but I am not a superuser, so please give explicit explanations for any advanced function so that I might be able to do more than copy/paste! :)

NB: I defined a `\citeframe` command to add keynumber in text and a `\rightsource` to add abbreviated citation as a footnote, but if you know how to get both with only one function (by changing `cite` for example) that would be all the better. Just beware that there could be multiple citations in one frame, then each citation should be displayed per line in the footnote.