# Overriding fields in a BibTeX file

Tags: bibtex

I keep all my references in one huge BibTeX file, which happens to include the full journal name for each one. I'm currently preparing a manuscript that needs the journal names to be abbreviated.

From the research I've done (including reading related questions on this site), it seems that (i) there is no standard automatic way to do this, but (ii) there are various tools such as `biber` and `jabref` that will allow me to pre-process my `.bib` file with a sort of global seach-and-replace for the journal names.

However, since my manuscript only has a few references it would be easier to just manually type in the new journal name for each entry. Is there a way to do this? I'm looking for a quick-and-dirty LaTeX-only solution that won't require me to install anything that isn't already part of TeX Live, since I'm on a tight schedule. I know I could just edit the entries in my .bib file, but I don't want to do that, because I like to keep all my references in the same place.

In case it's relevant, I maintain my `.bib` file using BibDesk on a Mac, I'm using the [`natbib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) package, and the bibliography style is `apalike`.

Comment: For the sake of portability, what I do is extract (using `bibtool`) from my main `bibliography.bib` file the relevant references for the particular project once it's done (or very, very close to being done).  This is better for long term portability, especially since you can now archive the `.tex` file along with the `.bib` and any custom `.sty` or `.cls` (etc.) you used to create the document.  If you go this route, there is nothing 'wrong' with hard-coding journal abbreviations into the new/local `.bib` file; in fact this would be the smart thing to do!  (But I also encourage using `biber`.)

Comment: @jon thanks for the suggestion - I might do that if a better way doesn't come up. There's a trade-off between long-term portability and medium-term editability, though. When my paper comes back from the reviewers I might need to add extra references, and in that case I either have to add the new ones to both `.bib` files, or I have to do the extraction and manual editing all over again. I realise that keeping everything in one big `.bib` file is fragile, but this is the reason I prefer to do it anyway.

Comment: True -- I usually to the extraction after the article has been accepted: like I said, when it is *done* (or when I think it is, at least).  And I've never had to deal with forced journal abbreviations, which admittedly kind of complicates things....

Answer (score 9):

I think that your restrictions of not installing anything make a simple solution difficult, so I will suggest the following solution based on this answer.

[How to abbreviate journal name in citation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66821/2693)

1. Download the `jabbrv` package from here: http://www.compholio.com/latex/jabbrv/
2. Download the `jabbrv_apalike.bst` from here: https://github.com/amunn/random-code/blob/main/jabbrv_apalike.bst (I created this file based on the the other `.bst` files included with the package.)
3. If you're really in a hurry, add the `jabbrv_apalike.bst` file to the `jabbrv` folder and place your TeX document in that folder too. (This is the fastest way to not install anything).

If you want to install things properly you should install the package in your local `texmf` folder in the following places (you'll need to create the `jabbrv` folders yourself).  On a Mac, the `<path-to-your-local-texmf>` = `~/Library/texmf`.

- Put `*.bst` in `<path-to-your-local-texmf>/bibtex/bst/jabbrv`
- Put  `jabbrv.sty` in `<path-to-your-local-texmf>/tex/latex/jabbrv`
- Put `*.ldf` in `<path-to-your-local-texmf>/tex/latex/jabbrv`

In your TeX document add the following line to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[warnundef]{jabbrv}
```

And change your bibliography style command:

```
 \bibliographystyle{jabbrv_apalike}
```

Check the warnings for any words that were not abbreviated, and for those words, add the lines like the following to your preamble:

```
\DefineJournalAbbreviation{long name}{abbreviation} % No period at the end
```

It took me longer to write this answer than to get an existing document of mine working with this package.

Answer (score 7):

one approach to normalizing journal (and publisher) names is to use the `@String` function in your `.bib` file.  for example,

```
@String{j-CACM = "Communications of the ACM"}
```

would give you the full name, while

```
@String{j-CACM = "Comm. ACM"}
```

would be substituted when abbreviations are needed.

the specific entry would then include

```
@Article{...,
  ...
  journal = j-CACM,
  ...,
}
```

(no quotes).  parallel collections of full titles or abbreviations could then be substituted as needed.  this also avoids possible problems of inconsistent typing of names in the individual entries.

this approach, along with much other information regarding maintenance of bibtex databases, was presented by nelson beebe at the 2004 practical tex conference, and resulted in [an extensive article on the topic](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb25-1/beebe-bib.pdf).  (nelson knows more about, and has more experience with, bibtex bibliographies than anyone else i know.  his recommendations are solid and well worth examining.)

Comment: Thanks, Barbara. I knew there was a way to do this in the bib file, but couldn't find the documentation for it.

Comment: The `@STRING` constants can be even in a different file. I have a `journal-abbrv.bib` defining only the strings of abbreviated journal names, and similarly a `journal-full.bib` defining the same constants `j-CACM` etc., but with full journal names. Then, I can easily switch between `\bibliography{journal-abbrv,hugebib}`, and `\bibliography{journal-full,hugebib}`.

Comment: @mafp -- thanks for that info.  (i knew it existed, but i couldn't find the syntax quickly.)  makes things *really* easy for an author!  (but if submitting to a publisher, it's still highly desirable, if not mandatory, to send just the relevant material, in as few files as possible.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Indeed.

Comment: (A point for future readers, not mafp or barbara beeton.)  When submitting to a journal, it may be wise to concatenate the 'strings' file and the bibliography file, which is easy to do; e.g., `cat journal-abbrv.bib hugebib.bib > article.bib`.  I would further recommend using `bibtool` to pare down the submitted bibliography to only the relevant references.  An article with fifty references does not require a database of 2000.