# How to automatically interpret full name of a journal to an abbreviation one, if string has blank space between words in the journal entry?

Tags: citing, ieeetran, ieee-style

I tried this,  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111725/44227,  it works only for string has no **blank space** between words in the journal entry, for example

---

**MWE:**

`Case 1: without blank space in Journal entry`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
 @article{ugrinovskii13,
 doi = {10.1109/tac.2013.2256675},
 author={Valery Ugrinovskii},
 volume = {58},
 number = {10},
 pages = {2659-2664},
 title = {Conditions for Detectability in Distributed Consensus-Based Observer   Networks},
 journal =TAC
     }
 \end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{abbr.bib}
@STRING{TAC   = "IEEE trans. Automat. Contr."}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\cite{ugrinovskii13}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{abbr,test}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

`Case 2: with blank space in Journal entry`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
 @article{ugrinovskii13,
 doi = {10.1109/tac.2013.2256675},
 author={Valery Ugrinovskii},
 volume = {58},
 number = {10},
 pages = {2659-2664},
 title = {Conditions for Detectability in Distributed Consensus-Based Observer   Networks},
 journal = IEEE Transactions on Automatic Control
}
 \end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{abbr.bib}
@STRING{IEEE Transactions on Automatic Control  = "IEEE trans. Automat. Contr."}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\cite{ugrinovskii13}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{abbr,test}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

The difference between two cases lying in `journal` and `@STRING`.

My question is that how to solve the `Case 2` problem without using `Case 1` solution, that is, I want preserve the journal entry in `Case 2`.

Comment: `how it works only for string has no blank space between words` : I don't understand. Please provide [a MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe)

Comment: Did you try `{IEEE} Tra....` instead? And `t` is capitalized in the compressed form. JabRef has an option to shorten or expand journal names. And it has been done already https://github.com/JabRef/reference-abbreviations/blob/master/journals/journal_abbreviations_ieee.txt

Comment: @Clément I have rewritten my question, and a `MWE` is provided as well.

Comment: @percusse I had updated my question, I'm afraid the previous version is not clear enough, I edited `{IEEE} Tra....` in the `journal` and `@STRING` entries, it came out the same way, but `IEEE` instead of `ieee`.

Comment: @percusse I visited https://github.com/JabRef/reference-abbreviations/blob/master/journals/journal_abbreviations_ieee.txt, it seems to me it just provided a list for journal abbreviation of IEEE,  what about the journal outsides the IEEE?

Comment: https://github.com/JabRef/reference-abbreviations/tree/master/journals

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do BibTeX with Case 2, you get

```
Database file #1: abbr.bib
I was expecting an "="---line 1 of file abbr.bib
 : @string{ieee 
 :              Transactions on Automatic Control  = "IEEE trans. Automat. Contr."}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
```

What does it mean? That a string abbreviation ***cannot*** contain spaces.

Dead end. You ***can't*** have spaces in a string abbreviation, because the BibTeX language doesn't allow it.

---

Why does the error message show `ieee`? Because BibTeX normalizes string abbreviations to lowercase; whether you type `TAC` `tac` `TaC` in the first example is unimportant: they all refer to the same string.

---

What can you do instead? Use two string files:

#### File `abbrv.bib`

```
@STRING{ IEEETAC = "IEEE Trans. Automat. Contr."}
```

#### File `full.bib`

```
@STRING{ IEEETAC = "IEEE Transactions on Automatic Control"}
```

Then you can have your item in the form

```
@article{ugrinovskii13,
  doi = {10.1109/tac.2013.2256675},
  author={Valery Ugrinovskii},
  volume = {58},
  number = {10},
  pages = {2659-2664},
  title = {Conditions for Detectability in Distributed Consensus-Based Observer   Networks},
  journal = IEEETAC
}
```

and load

```
\bibliography{abbr,test}
```

when you want abbreviated names or

```
\bibliography{full,test}
```

when you want full names.