# How can I recolor each part of citations in BibTeX?

Tags: bibtex, formatting, color

I can't find a way to color each part of a reference just like the attached image.

I am using BibTeX to create bibliographic references along with the style [`aasjournal.bst`](http://journals.aas.org/authors/aastex/aasjournal.bst), but there are two problems:

1. I want the name of journals to be abbreviated, for example show ApJ, not Astrophysical Journal.
2. I want the citation inside the paper be in the way that the names is black but he years are blue.

[image: example_pic]

Comment: The isseus you listed aren't really related. On TeX.SX you usually ask one question each post.

Comment: please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: To recolour each part of an entry, you will need to modify the bibliographical style file, but we don't know what that is, or possibly post-process the `.bbl` file, but we don't know how that is created in your case. Abbreviating journal titles also may be done in a variety of ways (I recommend using `@string`), but we don't know what you are up to on this point, either....

Comment: I think you can just cancel out the first of your two questions. It got alredy answered anayway here on TeX.SX: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111724/is-there-a-transparent-way-to-automatically-abbreviate-journal-names