Compact unsrt sty
Am looking for a BibTeX style file that, like unsrt, sorts by citing order and gives a numerical reference, but that is compact and lists only:

First author et al only (initials not necessary)
Abbreviated journal name
Volume and page in any order
Year (no month)

Other entries should be similarly compact.
This is for use with zotero linked to overleaf, with BibTeX.  I don’t want to modify the zotero entries.
I have looked at this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482291/239826, but it doesn’t abbreviate the journal and it lists the month.

Have you considered using biblatex instead of bibtex? Biblatex is usually much easier to customise.

According to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/711957/ Zotero can create journal abbreviations automatically on export (while keeping the original entries unmodified).

@Marijn that's good to know, but as far as I can tell, it doesn't work when Zotero is linked to overleaf and the bibliography is shared automatically, as opposed to exported manually.
