# Vancouver biblatex referencing style

Tags: biblatex

I'm a bit confused when it comes to the styling of references/bibliographies in biblatex.

How would I go about achieving the following?

- Vancouver style i.e.:

  - No italics, bold or underlining.
  - Author of article AA, Author of article BB, Author of article CC. Title of article. Abbreviated Title of Journal. Year; vol(issue):page number(s).
- Citations are numbered in the order of appearance in the text.
- Reference numbers are placed in square brackets [1] in the text.
- References cited in a table or figure legend are numbered after the citations in the text.

Comment: It's always the best to ask only one question for one issue. In addition it's the best providing a small minimal working example.

Comment: For my money, this is a bit of a "do-that-for-me" post (no offense). @Ben: have you consulted the documentation yet? I'm having my doubts... Getting rid of, for example, italicized titles is a matter of of just one line: `\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}` (as opposed to the default `{\emph{#1}}`. Numeric, unsorted citation style with square brackets? `style=numeric` (which is the default anyway), etc.

Comment: FYI.  It is probably not `issue`, but `number` that you want according to the description in the `biblatex` manual: `issue`: "The issue of a journal. this field is intended for journals whose individual issues are
identified by a designation such as 'Spring' or 'Summer' rather than the month or a number. [...]"

Comment: In addition to the points raised by Marco Daniel, Nils L and jon, the information provided is not actually sufficient to modify a complete style (What is the output of `@book` or `@online` supposed to look like? What about name formatting [last, first or first last etc.]?) Many of the requirements you mention can be implemented easily; some are not that trivial, but have been solved here. If you have trouble with any specific requirement ask away.

Comment: ...  A candidate for an interesting question might be the last point (number refernces in float objects after text). Very good ideas on how to abbreviate journal names can be found in [How to abbreviate journal name in citation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33441/35864).

Comment: Ended up doing it manually in the end.

Comment: @Ben In that case, would you care to provide an answer?

Comment: I formatted all of my references manually by hand in a word process and pasted them in. I had a deadline and couldn't spare the time to go through documentation etc. unfortunately.