# biber configuration file for shortening journal names

Tags: biblatex, biber

I found [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33441/how-to-abbreviate-journal-name-in-citation) and it seems it's possible to do a regular expression match to replace journal names while creating the bibliographic entries. 
So I wrote a configuration file with this contents:

```
<map>
  <bibtex>
  BMAP_OVERWRITE 1
    <globalfield journal>
      BMAP_MATCH Physical\sReview
      BMAP_REPLACE "Phys. Rev."
    </globalfield>
  </bibtex>
</map>
```

but I get this error:

```
:4: parser error : Specification mandate value for attribute journal
    <globalfield journal>
                        ^
```

Any guidelines on how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.conf` file format has changed quite a bit since then,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" level="user">
      <map map_overwrite="1">
        <map_step map_field_source="journal" map_match="Physical\sReview" map_replace="Phys. Rev."/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

should do the right thing now.

The [Biber documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/biber/documentation/biber.pdf) is a good place to start your research. Have a look at §3.1.2. *The `sourcemap` option*, pp. 13-20, esp. p. 17 where we have the example

```
<map map_overwrite="0">
  <map_step map_field_source="AUTHOR" />
  <map_step map_field_set="SORTNAME" map_origfieldval="1" map_final="1"/>
  <map_step map_field_source="SORTNAME" map_match="\A(.+?)\s+and. ∗ " map_replace="$1"/>
</map>
```

---

Of course you can also have a `\DeclareSourcemap` in your `.tex` document

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=journal, 
            match=\regexp{Physical\sReview},
            replace=\regexp{Phys. Rev.}]
    }
  }
}
```

which does the same, but is easier to keep track of, I find. It is easy to forget about a `biber.conf` and be confused about the output, with the sourcemapping done in the `.tex` file at least one is more likely to see the relevant code.