# Abbreviate journal name in bibtex using @string

Tags: bibtex, citing, acronyms, journal

I am trying to abbreviate the journal name while using bibtex. My approach it to use an additional file for substitution as mentioned in the following question on this forum: [How to abbreviate journal name in citation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33441/how-to-abbreviate-journal-name-in-citation) and also here [on linux.org](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=690).

Main tex file is this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

%opening
\title{Just a theory}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
A general treatment based on the work of Small and Big\cite{small1955} is presented which is extended for computing relevant values under the Harmonic oscillator approximation\cite{big1955}. 
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
A general treatment based on the work of Small and Big\cite{small1955} is presented which is extended for computing relevant values under the Harmonic oscillator approximation\cite{big1955}. A general treatment based on the work of Small and Big\cite{small1955} is presented which is extended for computing relevant values under the Harmonic oscillator approximation\cite{big1955}. 
\section{Section first}
A general treatment based on the work of Small and Big\cite{small1955} is presented which is extended for computing relevant values under the Harmonic oscillator approximation\cite{big1955}. 

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{abbr,ref}

\end{document}
```

And the abbr file and ref file are following:
abbr.bib

```
@string{3D Printing and Additive Manufacturing="3D Print. Addit. Manuf."}
@string{Advances in Complex Systems="Adv. Complex Syst."}
```

ref.bib

```
@article{small1955,
author = {Freely, I.P.},
title = {A small paper},
journal = {Advances in Complex Systems},
year = 1955,
volume = {1}
}

@article{big1955,
author = {Jass, Hugh},
title = {A big paper},
journal = {3D Printing and Additive Manufacturing},
year = 7991
}
```

I also tried this;

```
@string{3D Printing and Additive Manufacturing={3D Print. Addit. Manuf.}}
@string{Advances in Complex Systems={Adv. Complex Syst.}}
```

which also does not abbreviate the journal title. Present output is following;

[image: Reference section]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the following.

In your `abbr.bib`:

```
@string{threedprint="3D Print. Addit. Manuf."}

@string{AdCompSys="Adv. Complex Syst."}
```

And in your `ref.bib`:

```
@article{small1955,
author = {Freely, I.P.},
title = {A small paper},
journal = AdCompSys,
year = 1955,
volume = {1}
}

@article{big1955,
author = {Jass, Hugh},
title = {A big paper},
journal = threedprint,
year = 7991
}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Notice I've made three kinds of changes there. First, in your defined strings in `abbrv.bib`, instead of a long string name with spaces and all, a short one without them. Think of it as the `key` by which you call the string you defined. Second, when calling the string in `ref.bib` you do so without braces. It is not a field, it is a string defined somewhere else. Third, for reasons I don't know, letting the key start with a number ("3D") threw me an error, so I changed it to `threedprint`.