# Remove extra space in abbreviated journal title with jabbrv?

Tags: bibtex, packages, programming, jabbrv

I would like to abbreviate journal titles in my bibliography. One method employs the `jabbrv` package (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66821/293248), in particular with files from this Overleaf template (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/automatic-journal-abbreviations/mxfsdscmvxcr). Even in the template as is, there are extra blank spaces sometimes at the beginning of the abbreviated title, and always when certain characters are removed (those defined by `\DefineSpuriousJournalWord{}` in `jabbrv.sty`). I have read through the `jabbrv` package documentation as well as relevant posts about the package , and did not see the problem being mentioned anywhere.

[image]

For example, in the screenshot above, notice the extra space before

> [11] ... *Two MyAbbrv.,* ...

and

> [13] ... *Tes. J. Ref. Inf.,* ...

Also, in entry [13], whereas the full journal title should be "Test Journal of Reference Information", after "of" is removed, the space following it remains, resulting in what looks like a double-spaces.

In `jabbrv.sty` from the Overleaf template, starting from line 290, the space after a `SpuriousJournalWord` is not identified along with the word itself, which makes sense because a space is used as a delimiting character.

```
% Define Suprious Word Removal:
\providecommand{\DefineSpuriousJournalWord}[1]{%
    \expandafter\def\csname journal@abbrv@#1\endcsname{%
        \@gobble@space@true%
        \journal@output@space%
    }%
}
\DefineSpuriousJournalWord{of}
\DefineSpuriousJournalWord{in}
\DefineSpuriousJournalWord{and}
\DefineSpuriousJournalWord{the}
```

I suppose if one could solve the problem by making a "special case" for the space after such a word (though it does not help with or explain why there is also an extra space at the beginning of the journal title), my limited LaTex coding skill did not allow me quite come up with a solution.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I'm far from expert regarding `.bst` files, but it seems to me that `\@gobble@space@true` operates in the "forward" direction, whereas it's the preceding space that is relevant.  That would call for something more like `\unskip`.  Also, but irrelevant. the `%` on that line and the next shouldn't be necessary.  (Others are.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" the problem by rolling back to commit `f00da3a`, following the package creator's suggestion for another (possibly unrelated) issue here: https://github.com/compholio/jabbrv/issues/36#issuecomment-1337852860.